# How to extend esxOSDATA partition to use as datastore (or something?)

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-esx

I have installed esxi 8.0.1 on a new HP G10 with the following config:

- USB drive as boot installation media for ESX
- A 2TB Nvme for esxosdata!
- Some other SSD as single RAID10 array.

The problem is:

- ESX only used the first ~ 130GB of the 2TB Nvme Device and the remainder is left unusable.I need to use the remainder for some VMs.
  Two options:
- extend via command and use as data store.
- Create new partition and add as a data store (Preferred)

My knowledge(so far):

- The store partition cannot be extended via UI and should be done with SSH.
  -I know we can migrate esxosdata to a new partition (complex) [As Describe here](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Migrate_vSphere_(ESXi)_Installation_to_a_new_Storage_Device)

My Question:

1. Which is the better method to use the free space on NVME for VMs side by side with esxosdata?

Tried extending the datastore via Vsphere UI, Not possible with error:

```
Failed - Cannot change the host configuration.
Errors

    Failed to update disk partitions for /vmfs/devices/disks/...
```

Best